# Setup Azure Pipelines from Visual Studio 2017 Community

Tags: azure, azure-devops, visual-studio-2017, azure-pipelines

I am facing an issue with setup of azure pipelines. I am stuck with this window, where it will not give me any option to select azure project.
[image]

Here is what I have done already.
created a repo on github.
created an AzureDevOps account and created a project.
Build agent is setup along with build configurations in AzureDevOps which is getting the source from GitHub repo.

How can I get my AzureDevOps project to be populated in the given image?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I found a crude way to fix this issue, this may not be the ideal solution. 
Now I am able to see the azure devops project. It looked as if I have multiple Azure subscriptions mapped to my account and there was a conflict somewhere.

I deleted the %local% folder.
The absolute path is C:\Users***USERNAME***\AppData\Local

Comment: ☢️ CAUTION: That's a very drastic approach to fixing the issue. I'm guessing that either removing the `Appdata\Local\Azure DevOps` or the `AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation`  or `\AppData\Local\.IdentityService` would have done the trick without losing way more data stored by many other applications.

Comment: It would probably have worked as well if you signed out of Azure and Azure DevOps from Visual Studio Accounts panel, closed visual studio, restarted and signed back in.